# Is the inverse relation between the DOS and the energy gradient in $k$-space only valid in 1D systems?

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-of-states

In my solid state course, I was taught that Van Hove singularities can be explained because the DOS follows:

$$\mathrm{DOS} \propto \frac{1}{\nabla_k E} .$$

However, the DOS of a 3D system is proportional to $\sqrt{E-E_0}$, therefore, at the bottom of the band where $E=E_0$, it has a minimum. Does this mean that the above relationship only holds for 1D systems?